# Is it possible to send Azure DevOps service hook-webhook to log analytics custom table

Tags: azure-devops, webhooks, azure-service-hooks

What I want to do is to generate Azure monitor alerts for Azure DevOps pipeline failures.

We think we may achieve this without having to modify our DevOps YAML pipelines. So we focused on using Azure DevOps Service Hooks to do this by sending the pipeline log data  to the log analytics http data API.

I can send the data with Powershell. However I got a forbidden failure when testing the service webhook in Azure DevOps.

So I wonder if there is any missing operations?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYpJo.png)